# Can I use Fine Uploader with a flash based site?

Tags: flash, fine-uploader

I am trying to find out if I can upload a file by drag and drop from desktop to flash. I know Flash does not support this (unless its an air app, which I can not use), so I need a middle man. What I need to know is if Fine Uploader can still detect the drag drop if the flash movie is using all the browser real estate...?

Comment: My honest answer to this question is: "I don't know".  I've never tried this before.  It should be simple enough to test though.  First off, are you planning on using FineUploaderBasic mode, or FineUploader mode?

Comment: I am guessing FineUploader mode

Comment: Well, in that case, where are you going to display all of the UI elements created by Fine Uploader if the entire screen is taken up by a video?  FineUploader mode includes a pre-built customizable UI for displaying file progress, names, sizes, etc.

Comment: this is the issue I have, unless I can catch the dragOverEvent, then place a drop area, UI holder over the top of flash, i am stuck. Can you now see my problem.... ;)

Comment: What I am saying is that you have additional problems if the entire window is spoken for by the flash video.  Have you tried this out yet?  You would need to contribute some values to properties in the `dragAndDrop` option.

Comment: At the moment I am seeing what options there are available to me before I spec out a plan of action to show my boss.. I just have not found much in the way of drag drop file upload, when flash is involved. If I did not have to deal with flash it would be a walk in the park..

Comment: I guess I'd like to to describe your application a bit more.  What feedback, related to the uploaded file(s), do you plan on displaying to the user on this page?  What is this page, exactly?  If you could, please add these details to your original question.  The answers, in some ways, may affect the approach you take here.

Comment: I think this is not possible through a web browser, yes air has this ability and different access but web base content, im sure this would be a security issue